# How to use async/await in Typescript without global Promise Polyfill

Tags: typescript, es6-promise, polyfills

I am building an third party library for usage in browsers and want to use Typescript. Unfortunately I have to support Internet Explorer 11 and therefor include a Promise polyfill. As third party library i don't want to override globals like `window.Promise` as the website which uses the library may or may not use its own polyfills with different behavior.

With babel I could use the `regenerator-runtime` to transform Promises without a global polyfill and I would like to know if there is a similar solution for typescript without using Babel.

I already tried using `promise-polyfill`:

```js
import Promise from "promise-polyfill";

function testA(t) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, t);
  });
}

async function testB() {
  return true;
}
```

Function `testA` is correctly polyfilled in the generated javascript code but `testB` is not. The typescript transform for async/await doesn't seam to care for the imported Promise polyfill.

Comment: What is your build target in tsconfig? I think you should set it to ~es5 for ie11 so the compiled code will be transformed and will be able to use the promise polyfill. (see the following example: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20test%20%3D%20async%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log('')%0D%0A%7D)

Comment: It doesn't work. The Promise polyfill is not included even with target es5

Comment: You have to add "import 'promise-polyfill/src/polyfill';" anyways. ES5 target will allow you to use the async-await syntax.